# Microservice writes wide unstructured parquet file to data lake

Tags: pyspark, microservices, azure-synapse

I have a microservice that when records are created or modified puts a message onto a service bus that then writes that message to an Azure Storage account in my data lake.  This message is over 1024 columns which triggers the following error when trying to query it

```
SELECT * 
  FROM
       openrowset(BULK 'https://container.blob.core.windows.net/datalake/Bronze/ServiceBus/Object/2023-03-22-18-31-07-530-object.parquet', FORMAT = 'parquet')
       AS ROWS
-- Number of columns in the data file 'https://container.blob.core.windows.net/datalake/Bronze/ServiceBus/Object/2023-03-22-18-31-07-530-object.parquet' exceeds the maximum of 1024.
```

Then when I attempt to read the file in Synapse with PySpark I get a different error message because the microservice is only writing out non null columns. In this case I'm looking for AdditionalSpecialties_1_AdditionalSpecialtyId

```
spark.sql("""
SELECT 
    B.ObjectId,
    B.AdditionalSpecialties_0Id,
    B.AdditionalSpecialties_1Id,
    B.(over 1000 other columns describing an object)
FROM Bronze B 
""").createOrReplaceTempView("Bronze")
#org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`B.AdditionalSpecialties_1Id`' given input columns: [B.ObjectId, B.AdditionalSpecialties_0Id]
```

I'm new to data lake processing (as is my entire company) so I'm not sure if we are writing the file correctly, or if this is the correct way to write the file then how to read a file with a columns like AdditionalSpecialties_1Id not always in the parquet file (dataframe?) Each parquet file represents a different ObjectId.

What I'd like to know is if I have multiple parquet files in a directory that have the following properties:

| File Name | ObjectId | AdditionalSpecilties_0Id | AdditionalSpecialties_1Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| File1 | 112 | a | b |
| File2 | 22 |  |  |
| File3 | 78 | c |  |
| File4 | 456 | d | a |
| File5 | 14 | e |  |

A blank in this example above means that the column is not in the corresponding file, so File 3 does not have the column AdditionalSpecialties_1Id and I get the error above

How do use PySpark to read files with the same set of potential columns, but I don't know which columns will be in a specific file?